# IIS performance query while hosting multiple applications

Tags: iis, .net-core, web-hosting, devops

I have developed Web App and Web API in .Net Core 2.0 along with Xamarin Mobile App. I am looking for best hosting strategy so that I can have best cost effective performance. Basically I need to host two stuff

1. Web App
2. Web API.

Questions:

1. Should I use different domain for both applications. i.e. www.myapp.com & www.myapi.com. or
2. I should use subdomain or directory for webapi. i.e. www.api.myapp.com or www.webapi.com/api

Confusion:

I have windows dedicated server with average configuration. Per my understanding, In both case all traffic will route to the same server. No matter I start with question 1 or 2.

Please advice.

Comment: None of the options would really impact IIS performance. So do whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

With a single server it makes little difference which option you use. However domains/subdomains make it easier to scale/replace 1 or both components in the future.

Ask yourself:
Do you expect your app/api to ever require more than 1 server?
Do customers/3rd parties integrate with your api url directly?

If you answer yes to either question different domains/ subdomains probably make more sense.

Ideally within IIS I would have 2 seperate websites. One for `www.example.com` and a 2nd site `api.example.com`.

You should also think about a cdn (cloudflare ect) as this will help reduce load on you server and make static files load faster for end users.